# How does this differentiation simplify?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't understand how this simplifies:

> Differentiate $y=\left(3x^2\right)^{1/3}-(5x)^{-1/2}$.

$6x\times1/3=2x$. How does $3x^2$ interact with $\square^{-2/3}$ to produce $(9x4)^1/3$? Where does the $9$ come from?

$5\times1/2=5/2$. How does $5x$ interact with $^-3/2$ to produce $2(5x)(5x)/2$?

Why does the $4$ disappear in the next step? Why does the other $(5x)$ disappear? Why does $2$ gain an $x$?

Thanks.

Comment: It will help make your post readable if you were to format your equations using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.  [Here is a link on how to do so](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It is not clear which `x`'s above are meant to be multiplication ($\times$) and which are meant to be variables ($x$).

Comment: I agree with @JMoravitz : Please check the edit.

Comment: Can you add the given reasoning, or at least the final answer, to your post? It's hard to understand without knowing what the $(9 \times 4)/3$ and what not is referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule:  Let $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}G(x)=g(x)$

One has that $\frac{d}{dx}[F(G(x))] = f(G(x))g(x)$

Alternatively, written in Lagrange notation, $(f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$, or Leibniz notation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$

Differentiating something like $(3x^2)^{1/3}$, let $F(x)=x^{1/3}$ and $G(x)=3x^2$.

One sees that $F(G(x))=(3x^2)^{1/3}$

Applying the chain rule, we have then:  $\frac{d}{dx}[F(G(x))]=f(G(x))g(x)$, so what are each of these pieces?

Well, $F(x)=x^{1/3}$ so $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{1/3-1}=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$ by the power rule of differentiation.

Similarly, $G(x)=3x^2$ so $g(x)=2\cdot 3x^{2-1}=6x$

Putting this all together, we have $\frac{d}{dx}[(3x^2)^{1/3}]=\frac{1}{3}(3x^2)^{-2/3}\cdot 6x$

A way to remember this aloud in simpler terms, you "take the derivative of the outside as though the inside were normal, then multiply by the derivative of the inside."

The second piece is derived similarly.

---

Reminder:  The power rule of differentiation:  $\frac{d}{dx}[x^k]=kx^{k-1}$ for all $k\neq 0$

---

As for the meat of your question,  "*why does -insert object here- dissapear*," those are all from algebraic simplifications.

$\frac{2x}{(9x^4)^{1/3}}=\frac{2x}{(9x^3\cdot x)^{1/3}}=\frac{2x}{(x^3)^{1/3}(9 x)^{1/3}}=\frac{2x}{x\sqrt[3]{9x}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{9x}}$

Similarly for the other.

*edit: corrected notation attributions as per comment below*

Comment: You incorrectly attributed the [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange.27s_notation).  The notation you attribute to Leibniz (in German, the second vowel is pronounced) is actually due to Lagrange.  The notation you attribute to Newton is actually due to Leibniz.  Newton used dots above the function to denote the derivative, which is still used in physics to denote derivatives with respect to time.  The non-historical portion of your answer is excellent, as usual.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Huh... I'll need to read my history books again.  Thanks for correcting me, because I'm sure I've been misleading several people over the past while about that.